# QT 5 64-bit for Windows and VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, 64-bit

Trying to download **QT 5 for Windows** from [this web page](http://qt-project.org/downloads), I noted that the *64-bit* version is available only for VS2012, *not for VS2010*.

It seems that they use VS2010 for 32-bit, and VS2012 for 64-bit.

Does anyone know the reason for that?

Are there important blocking bugs in VS2010 64-bit C++ compiler that make it impossible to build QT?

Why is there no 64-bit QT for VS2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QT 5 64 bit version [can be compiled with MSVC-2010](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/2011/02/01/how-to-compile-qt-4-7-with-visual-studio-2010/#comment-7546).

There's still a risk that you encounter some problems (I had a lot with both 2010 and 2012 versions of MSVC).

Answer (score 3):

After a long search I found it here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/qtx64/files/qt-x64/5.1.0/msvc2010/

Answer (score 1):

This lib is abandoned:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/qtx64/

And I found another one instead: 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/qt64ng/

and it's repo is here, e.g. for v4.8.6 with vc10x64 compiled:
http://download2.polytechnic.edu.na/pub4/sourceforge/q/qt/qt64ng/qt/x86-64/4.8.6/msvc2010/